# javascript not working, onclick function

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

I have an HTML page with a heading and 2 Divs, I then have a javascript where I want the heading to change if the user selects one off the Divs.

https://jsfiddle.net/L27xqgfs/1/

```
var happyMood = getElementById("happy");
var sadMood = getElementById("sad");


happyMood.onclick = function () {
    var mainHeading = getElementById("heading");
    mainHeading.innerHTML = "You have selected ";

};

sadMood.onclick = function () {
    var mainHeading = getElementById("heading");
    mainHeading.innerHTML = "You have selected " + sadMood;
};
```

Please can someone advise where I've gone wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `getElementById()` is not a global function, try `document.getElementById()`. Start there.

Comment: `document.getElementById` not `getElementById`!

Comment: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L27xqgfs/3/)

Comment: Also after you make the change suggested in other comments, if you try to concatenate sadMood object with a string you won't get the result you would expect. Instead use its ID to get requested result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you call getElementById without any object,then you call `window. getElementById`, but you really should call `document.getElementById`. And you should import js file into html(in you local test).
I have created another [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fvsr8gmw/1/) which is correct.

Answer (score 0):

```
var happyMood = document.getElementById("happy");
var sadMood = document.getElementById("sad");


happyMood.onclick = function () {
   var mainHeading =     document.getElementById("heading");
    mainHeading.innerHTML = "You have selected ";

};

sadMood.onclick = function () {
var mainHeading =    document.getElementById("heading");
    mainHeading.innerHTML = "You have selected " +   sadMood;
};
```